# Would a graph db be a good fit for this kind of data

Tags: amazon-web-services, nosql, graph-databases

This is the essence of what the app I am creating does (simplified but its the general usage):

Users (who are authorized and authenticated using AWS Cognito and Federated Identities) can create/write articles. Other users can choose to read random articles (even if they are logged in as guests, but guests can't create articles). Users can also see articles they've written and how many people have read them, liked them etc. Articles can also be reported by Users (as inappropriate, incorrect etc) which can lead to the Article being deleted/hidden from other users after a review process.

There are also permissions that need to be provided for users if they abuse the app to prevent them from creating articles (or if they just go around reporting everything in sight to stop them from being allowed to report).

Currently I store the articles in a MySQL db and store information when an article is read liked using a NoSQL db(DynamoDB). I recently came across AWS AppSync which seems to store app data in a graph db.

All the data seems like a Graph db would be a good fit, except I need to be able to retrieve some number of random articles. Is that even possible in a graph db? It seems like that operation would be a bad fit for Graph dbs, but I've never used them so I am unsure.

Comment: Regarding AppSync, I think you may be confusing Graph DB with GraphQL, which is something quite different.